# Replacing my chain

Tags: chain

My chain broke recently.  I fixed it by taking out a link with a chain break tool.  Now the it slips when I am in my smallest gear on the cassette.  I cannot find the stiff link in my chain and think I should replace it.  What type of chain do I have to use.  One designed for Shimano?  Attached is a picture of my cassette if that helps determine what type of chain I need.[image]

Comment: The main thing you have to match is the chain width, which is determined by the number of rear cogs -- the more cogs, the narrower the chain.

Answer (score 5):

8 speed cassette
You need an 8 speed chain
7/8 is the same size